# Quartz.NET fail prevention/detection methods

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have nearly completed a Quartz.NET based Windows Service (using ADO.NET, not RAM jobs). The service copies/moves files to various paths depending upon a schedule. I have some concerns however. It is very important that this service has some sort of detection method/system that will detect when the program has failed for whatever reason - whether it's files failing to be copied, or the whole scheduler crashing . Just wondering what you guys think is the best way to do this? I have a couple of vague ideas but I'm looking to hear some more input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the methods that we use:

1. We monitor the windows service itself using the IT monitoring system. We use one of those commercial products that monitors servers, services, databases, etc, but there are open source projects that can do this for you if you don't already have one in place.
2. We log fatal execeptions to a database table and have a separate service monitoring that table for exceptions.
3. We also use an ADO.Net store, so we also monitor the Quartz.net tables for things like stuck triggers.

With things like this you can definitely go down the over engineering path. Just keep in mind the cost benefit of adding each of these options and then decide how much work you want to put into monitoring, VS the cost of an outage.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, they're some great suggestions and I'll be taking these into account.